# How to properly code/label form controls within a table

Tags: angular, accessibility, wcag2.0

Background: There is a table that has three columns and five rows. First column is "Alerts", second column is "Email" and the third is "Text". Each row has the Alerts description with checkboxes under the Email and Text columns for users to opt in or out to receive notifications.

Question: Do the checkboxes need to have associated labels? The form controls (checkboxes) do not have associated labels but are contextual to the table. Ex. User reads alert type, goes to second column to check/uncheck checkbox to opt in for email alerts and same for third column with a checkbox for text alerts. From a screen reader perspective it's still comprehensible due to the context of the column headers and rows but are the labels ABSOLUTELY necessary for WCAG 2.1 AA accessibility requirements?

Comment: Label is just label - either use it or not. Does not have influence on checkbox

Comment: Thanks but I'm referring to WCAG accessibility standards and whether or not they're a must have in this scenario. Specifically WCAG criteria 1.3.1 Info and Relationships and criteria 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions.

Comment: `"Label is just label - either use it or not. Does not have influence on checkbox"` - I absolutely **disagree**.  It has **tremendous** influence on the checkbox.  A checkbox without a label is just a floating box with no purpose.  The label also increases the target size - you can click on the box or the box's label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: You don't have to have a `<label>`. The WCAG has other means of achieving the same goal, like using an adjacent button: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G167.html

The user should be able to easily determine the purpose of the checkbox, and a screen-reader should be able to hear a (preferably unique) name / description when focusing the checkbox.

It sounds to me like the "*Alert type*" (if unique) could be used as the label associated with the checkbox. The checkbox should have some kind of accessible name anyway.

Comment: I would set "E-mail" and "Text" as check box labels, because this info is more difficult to get than the alert type; that's only one way of doing it, though.

Comment: I now see that the checkboxes are described as belonging to the Email column and to the Text column, so I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: G167 might satisfy 3.3.2 so that the input field has label (the example in that URL), but it would still **fail** 4.1.2 if that label is not programmatically associated with the input.  The user would tab to the input and **not** hear "search".

Comment: A note to my future self that https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H65 may be the better reference, specifically "Example 4: A data table of form controls".  Linked examples show a "title" attribute of each form control that references the column and row, such as "deposit amount for investment account" or "taxpayer dividends". Also from linked example https://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse8.htm:  "a user is going to be listening to these controls in forms mode, not in table reading mode, and in this situation the table headers are not spoken".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each value in the alert column is unique, you could assign an id to them and use the **aria-labelledby** attribute to link each checkbox element to its alert type, providing the needed programmatically associated label. With the proper table header markup, screen readers should announce the elements with both the header label and it's "alert type" label to provide the same context the table provides visually. From what I can tell, that should resolve any potential **1.3.1, 3.3.2, and 4.1.2** failure concerns. Try running the snippet using a screen reader to navigate through both the unlabelled and labelled table to see the difference.

*Relevant Snippet Code:*

```
<h2 id="tableLabel">Notification Preferences (labelled)</h2>
    <table aria-labelledby="tableLabel">
      <tr>
        <th>Alert Type</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Text Message</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="alertNewMessage">New Messages</td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertNewMessage" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertNewMessage" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="alertBillReminder">Billing Reminders</td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertBillReminder" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertBillReminder" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Using aria-labelledby with selection cells in a data table</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Notification Preferences (Unlabelled)</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Alert Type</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Text Message</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>New Messages</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Billing Reminders</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <h2 id="tableLabel">Notification Preferences (labelled)</h2>
    <table aria-labelledby="tableLabel">
      <tr>
        <th>Alert Type</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Text Message</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="alertNewMessage">New Messages</td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertNewMessage" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertNewMessage" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="alertBillReminder">Billing Reminders</td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertBillReminder" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input aria-labelledby="alertBillReminder" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

  </html>
```